Direct proof of $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational
Is there a way to directly prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational without using contradiction - the most popular method? I was thinking that maybe it could be done using a corollary of the completeness axiom... or maybe I am complete off. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Well, fundamentally it is not a statement about the real numbers, it is a statement about rational numbers, and can be restated as a statement about natural numbers. You don't need the existence of a value $\sqrt2$ to state that no rational, when squared, returns $2.$

To put this another way, and to give you something to prove without using contradiction: for every rational number $m/n$, $m^2/n^2 \ne 2$.
